# Can I use Crashlytics only for C++ crash reporting?

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I have an app with Java and C++ code. Is it possible for me to only use Crashlytics to catch C++ crashes and not Java crashes? I tried using 
`Fabric.with(this, new CrashlyticsNdk());`
but that gives me an error about Crashlytics needing to be initialized.

Edit: I don't mind using Crashlytics for Java crashes, but management is hard to convince. As far as they're concerned, our existing crash reporting solution works for Java crashes (but it doesn't work too well for native crashes) so the 'ideal' solution is to use Crashlytics only for C++ crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Firebase here. No, the NDK SDK needs to have Crashlytics present in order to report everything correctly.

Comment: Is there any hope for this feature being present in the future? Or is it unlikely?

Comment: It's not planned - can you share why you don't want Java crashes captured?